# What norm makes $C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R}^n)$ into a Banach space?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces

I am reading some literature where they refer to

> "the Banach space of all $C^1$ maps from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$."

But they don't say what norm they are using to make this into a Banach space. Is there a natural/standard choice of norm on this space which works?

My guess is that
$$\|f\|=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|+\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f'(x)|.$$
But I am not sure if this gives a Banach space. Is it?
(Additionally, I would be interested to see a textbook reference of this material.)

Comment: Here's another similar norm: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/space-of-all-continuously-differentiable-functions

Comment: Also, [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=oOYQVeHmNk4C&lpg=PA59&ots=XLoSOlWQH6&pg=PA59#v=onepage&q&f=false) calls your proposed norm the $C^1$-norm.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Say you have a Cauchy sequence $\{f_n\}$ in the $C^1$ norm you propose.  Then in particular $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in $C^0$ and so converges uniformly to a continuous function $f$.  Likewise $\{f_n'\}$ is Cauchy in $C^0$ and converges uniformly to a continuous function $g$.  Since $$f_n(x) = f_n(0) + \int_0^x f_n'(t) \, dt,\quad x \in [0,1]$$ holds for all $n$, you can let $n \to \infty$ and get $$f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x g(t) \, dt,\quad x \in [0,1].$$ Thus $f \in C^1$ and $f' = g$ so that $f_n \to f$ in your $C^1$ norm.

Comment: this does not answer the op's question (which norm are you using).

Comment: Great, thanks. But would you say that it is the most natural choice of norm which makes it Banach? Do you know any other?